# Priority for duplicate questions and answers?

Tags: discussion, policy

The question [Sci-fi book about “the Wall” and a group of schoolchildren who fight the dark forces who roam north of it](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/18177/31393) was asked in 2012, and [answered](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/18184/31393) in 2012, and the answer accepted in 2012.

The above question was marked as a duplicate of [Book with a main character who uses bells to dispel the dead](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/236278/31393), which was asked in 2020 (3 hours ago), and [answered](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/236280/31393) in 2020, and the answer was accepted in 2020.

Shouldn't the 'This question already has an answer here' be applied to the 2020 question and accepted answer, and not the 2012 question and accepted answer?

Are we agnostic about duplicates priority? Or is there some other criterion to be used?

Comment: I believe the older one should be closed as a duplicate of the newer one in accordance with the linked policy since the question for the newer one is slightly more descriptive.